# Can any one tell how to get Optimized Css, Js, Images from google insights new version

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Can any one tell how to get Optimized Css, Js, Images from google insights new version. like old vertion

Thanks

Comment: I believe they removed this feature in version 5 of PageSpeed Insights :(

Comment: I'd also like to know that, is there any way to get the optimized_contents zip file?